# TypeScript Cannot find name 'ClassName' even-though exported Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-plugins

I have to use certain plugins in my Ionic 3 Application but it gives   Cannot find name error. I imported

`import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';`

and on on declaring in constructor `(public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions)`, it gives an error `([ts] Cannot find name 'AndroidPermissions'.)` .

On declaring the same plugin in app.module.ts and declaring in Provider, it gave the error

```
[ts]
Type 'AndroidPermissionsOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
Type 'AndroidPermissionsOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactory [2322]
```

After reading forums, I imported the plugin with ngx.

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx'
```

Error got resolved, but on invoking it throws the error

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at AndroidPermissions.requestPermissions (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/vendor.js:69796:154)
    at http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/main.js:138:32
    at t.invoke (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33)
    at t.invoke (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
    at t.invokeTask (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://192.168.0.13:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
```

Similar error happened when using [Network plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) and [SMS plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/).

Also tried changing the target to es6 and jib to have es2016 in tsconfig.json but noting worked.
 Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ionic version 3 (not the latest one) Please refer below mention docs 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/android-permissions/

first remove
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-android-permissions

re add it with

> $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
>
> $ npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions@4

Comment: I migrated to Ionic 4 and using the imports with ngx prefix worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try these commands
 - remove package-lock.json

`ionic cordova platform remove android
npm install
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions@4`

Comment: I migrated to Ionic 4 and using the imports with ngx prefix worked. Thanks.